# maximum recursion depth exceeded converting pandas dataframe to pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, beautifulsoup, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am very new to pyspark and learning to create a pyspark dataframe from a list of Beautiful soup bs4.element.Tag objects

```
table = bsoup.findAll(name='tr')
table = [tr.findAll(name='td') for tr in table]
table = [list(tr) for tr in table]

table
[[<td>City\n    </td>, <td>Country \n  </td>],
[<td>Paris</td>, <td>France</td>],
[<td>Amsterdam</td>, <td>Holland</td>]]

type(table[0][0])
bs4.element.Tag


spsession = SparkSession(sc)
spark_df = spsession.createDataFrame(table)

<path>/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/types.py in 
_infer_type(obj)
    967     else:
    968         try:
--> 969             return _infer_schema(obj)
    970         except TypeError:
    971             raise TypeError("not supported type: %s" % 
type(obj))

RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Looks like the problem happens during schema inference because bs4.element.Tag type is not getting inferred for some reason

I confirmed this by successfully creating a pyspark df from the  text content extracted from bs4.element.Tag objects instead of Tags and everything works fine.

Can someone please explain why the schema is not being inferred ? And how to fix this error and create a pyspark dataframe that contains bs4.element.Tag objects ?

p.s I tried increasing the recursionlimit to much higher values but the above error remains.
Increasing the recursionlimit to a very large value causes seg faults.

Comment: Why are you trying to convert a pandas DataFrame into a Spark DataFrame?  That doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: I edited the post to get rid of the pandas df to avoid any confusion.. Now I'm simply trying to create a pyspark dataframe from a list of beautifulsoup Tags and still running into "RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object"

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and I manually cast the `bs4.element.Tag` stuff as Strings before putting into `createDataFrame`